# What happens if I pass too few parameters to a shell function?

Tags: bash, shell, function

I would like to ask about passing parameters into functions. 
I tried this:

```
function_name $var1 $var2
```

but usually (sometimes it printed error) it didn't make any difference whether I passed them or not. I mean it perfectly worked when I called it only with `function_name`.  So my question is: Is it necessary to give there these parameters like in example above?

Comment: It depends almost entirely on what `function_name` does. (If `$var1` and `$var2` were empty/undefined then that would also be equivalent to omitting them, too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash doesn't check number of arguments passed to a function because there are no prototypes as in C. From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions:

> Shell functions are a way to group commands for later execution using
>   a single name for the group. They are executed just like a "regular"
>   command. When the name of a shell function is used as a simple command
>   name, the list of commands associated with that function name is
>   executed. Shell functions are executed in the current shell context;
>   no new process is created to interpret them.
>
> Functions are declared using this syntax:
>
> name () compound-command [ redirections ]
>
> or
>
> function name [()] compound-command [ redirections ]

One check inside function whether a number of arguments is correct and return an error if it's not but it's not Bash responsibility. See:

```
#!/bin/bash

function f()
{
    echo $1
}

function f1
{
    echo $1
}

f
f 2
f1
f1 f1
```

Comment: if i am missing argument data in a bash function f1() then i test by doing this as the first command in the function `echo "f1:" '$@" 1>&2`

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a function's arguments as numbered expansions in order of their appearance on the command-line when the function was called. If you wish to require that an argument is present in order for a function to operate, you can do this via an intrinsic failure-reference to the argument in question via parameter-expansion.

```
echo1()(
    printf %s\\n \
    "${1?This function requires an argument!}"
)
```

The above will either print the value *(if any)* for the function's first argument followed by a newline to stdout and return 0, or it will print a diagnostic message in your shell's format containing the phrase *This function requires an argument!* to stderr and return other than 0 if it is provided no arguments at all.

Note that the function is declared to run in a subshell like:

```
fn()( : body )
```

And not in the current shell like:

```
fn(){ : body; }
```

This is because the parameter substitution form used to raise the error causes the current shell to exit - and if the function runs in the current shell could therefore result in an unexpected exit of the current shell. This is only true of *non-interactive* shells, however. For example, whether or not the function were declared in a subshell the above function should behave similarly either way if called from a prompt.

But if the function were declared in a current shell and executed in a script, then the script would quit executing as a whole if `echo1` was called without any arguments.

Answer (score -1):

A function, like an external command, receives a list of parameters. There's no way to define a function that intrinsically requires a certain number of parameters. The code of the function can check the number of parameters and their value and emit error messages if it wishes.

The number of parameters passed to the current function is available in the special variable `$#`. If you use a numbered parameter which is larger than the number of actual parameters, that parameter is unset, so if you try to access it, you get an empty string. For example, with the following definition:

```
f () {
  echo "$#" "[[$2]]"
}
```

- `f` prints `0 [[]]`. Since there is no parameter number 2, `$2` expands to the empty string.
- `f one` prints `1 [[]]`, for the same reasons.
- `f one two` prints `2 [[two]]`.
- `f one two three` prints `3 [[two]]`. The function happens not to do anything with its third parameter, but that's ok.